# MPEGTS across devices has choppy audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player

I want to stream video and its audio between devices. On my pc I am transmitting it using

```
ffmpeg -re -i "video.mp4" -vcodec libx264 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.106:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

And on the receiving end I open it

```
udp://@192.168.1.109:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

in vlc.

The video is going through fine but the audio seems to be cutting out for a few seconds and then it comes back.

Comment: Try to increase the "Network Caching" as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/317470/is-there-a-way-to-tell-vlc-to-buffer-a-file-on-a-remote-pc-so-as-to-play-uninter). Try encoding the stream first, and transmit later: `ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -vcodec libx264 video.ts`, then: `ffmpeg -re -i "video.ts" -c copy -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.106:1234?pkt_size=1316`. Try streaming with lower bitrate: try encoding with `-b:v 1000k` for example.

Comment: Why packet size = 1316? Have you determined that's the optimal MTU size? See https://help.keenetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/214470885-How-to-determine-the-optimal-MTU-size